# kendo ui charts area, add stroke to series

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui to make an area chart. 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/chart-types/area-charts

I am trying to add a stroke to each series but I am not seeing the results

here is my code:

```
series: [{
    name: "vendor0",
    data: v0,
    color: "green",
    stroke: {
      color: "black",
      width: 3
    }

}, {
    name: "Vendor 1",
    data: v1
}, {
    name: "Vendor 6",
    data: v6
}],
```

Any advice on how to get that stroke, below is a screenshot of my work, and you can see how inline it says stroke = none[image]
here is an image of desired effect:

[image]

Comment: Also, if there is just a way to add class / id to each series that will also help me. thanks!

Comment: You could add a second line series for each area series that points to the same data:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IxEjO